# Android Studio showing error in valid Kotlin Code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I reformatted my mac recently and installed everything from scratch.
So I did it with Android Studio too and then I imported an existing project of mine.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, when I use `Long.parseLong()`, Android Studio is telling me that it is not a valid function but it is a valid function in Kotlin.

How do I fix this?

Previous Attempts to fix.
1. Reinstall JDK and JRE
2. Reinstall Android Studio
3. Clean and Rebuild gradle
4. Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

None of these steps worked.
What is wrong with my Android Studio?

Comment: Check your `import` statements if it is correct.

Comment: Yup. Got this `import java.util.*`

Comment: `Long` class is in the `java.lang` package, not `java.util`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Kotlin, not Java

Compiler tries to use Long class from the Kotlin library, the class doesn't have `parseLong()` method.

You have two options:

Fully qualify class (add the package name)

```
java.lang.Long.parseLong(msg.time)
```

Or more "Kotlin way"

```
msg.time.toLong()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parseLong(val);
```

Is a java method and this is Kotlin. Android Studio is working fine.

You don't need to do anything with Android Studio.